# AngularJS edit button work just once then TypeError: l is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm currently learning AngularJS and I'm building an address book. I have an edit button which work fine the first time but not the next one. It only show me this error which I do not understand.

```
TypeError: l is not a function
at angular.js:12234
at f (angular.js:22824)
at k.$eval (angular.js:14287)
at k.$apply (angular.js:14385)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:22829)
at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
at HTMLButtonElement.q.handle (jquery-3.1.1.min.js:3)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:11496
```

Here my minimal code.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  
 </head>
 <body ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="studentContoller" class="container">
  <h1> List of places</h1>
   <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
     <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Postal code</th>
      <th>City</th>
      <th></th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     <tr ng-repeat="item in addressBook">
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.address}}</td>
      <td>{{item.postal_code}}</td>
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>
       <button ng-show="item.isEditing != true" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-click="edit(item)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
       </button>
       <button ng-show="item.isEditing === true" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-click="submit(edit)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
       </button>
       <button ng-show="item.isEditing === true" type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" ng-click="cancelEdition(item)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
       </button>
      </td>
     </tr>

    </tbody>
   </table>
  </div>

  <script>
   function studentContoller($scope,$http){

    $scope.edit = function(item){
     item.isEditing = true;
     $scope.edit = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item)); // dirty deep copy
    }
    
    $scope.cancelEdition = function(item){
     item.isEditing = false;
    }
    $scope.submit = function(item){
     item.isEditing = false;
    }

    $scope.addressBook = [
     {"id": 187, "name": "Le Goff Raymond SA", "address": "8, place Diallo","postal_code": "93 224","city": "Paul"},
     {"id": 188,"name": "Gay","address": "2, rue de Deschamps","postal_code": "43092","city": "Pinto"},
     {"id": 190,"name": "Le Guillet","address": "8, chemin Payet","postal_code": "59 633","city": "Leclercq"},
     {"id": 191,"name": "Delorme S.A.R.L.","address": "864, impasse Lesage","postal_code": "00 950","city": "Gaudin"},
     {"id": 192,"name": "Normand SARL","address": "chemin de Lesage","postal_code": "90962","city": "Dufour-sur-Petitjean"},
     {"id": 193,"name": "Lucas SARL","address": "21, boulevard Deschamps","postal_code": "84196","city": "Joubert-les"}
    ]
   }

   angular.module("MyApp",[])
    .controller("studentContoller",studentContoller);
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

So I have two questions, what did I do wrong? And how could have debug it.

Thank in advance,

Comment: can you set us a jsfiddle for this ?

Comment: Switch the .min scripts for the full scripts to see a more friendly message. For example, include angular.js instead of angular.min.js.

Comment: Okay I'll do that thanks for the advice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the JSON.parse result to the same name as the function. That's why it doesn't work the second time. You have to use a different name.

```
$scope.edit = function(item){
    item.isEditing = true;
    $scope.edit_test = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item)); // dirty deep copy
}
```

Comment: I like that trick for doing the copy :). Does angular.copy not work for deep copies?